# SSIS Connection manager - Account userid getting locked

Tags: ssis

we are using SSIS 2016 and with parameterize connections. Every time we open the solution the connection manager is trying to connect with the credentials available in the project.param , due to unavailability of the password and repeated trying the db user account is getting locked.

Looking for some inputs if there is any settings we could change for connection manager not to try to connect when the solution is opened.

Thanks for your time on this.
RR

Answer (score 0):

If you change the project setting to work in Offline mode, you should be able to open the project without validation checks firing which should alleviate the ever-so-fun lockout policy. That might be a user solution file setting so each team member might need to set it.

A different approach is to leave the design time user value to a non existent account. The run-time will swap in the properly parameterized connection but any developer opening the packages won't lock anyone out.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ,we will try this.   Thanks for you time ..